# Cannot open source file; C++; Visual Studio

Tags: c++, include

I'm learning about dll files and trying to create one. 
My problem is that when i try to build my solution in visual studio, i'm getting errors saying e.g. "cannot open source file string.h".

This happens for multiple header files.  The error is produced by a file other than mine, which includes string.h

[error list from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj8o4.png)

I can't figure out how to fix this error, and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `#include <string>` instead of `<string.h>`.

Comment: @Gill Bates I don't think the errors he gets are due to his source code, rather due to Windows' headers (if I'm looking at the screenshot correctly)

Comment: @Asu Yeah, my first comment was "your compiler is broken, reinstall it" but that's kind of radical.

Comment: maybe visual studio include folder location is changed. please have a look

Comment: @Angelica, sorry if this is a dumb question but what should this include folder location be set to, and how do i change it?

Comment: @Frederik don't feel sorry. its just like image [VC Direcory] (https://s23.postimg.org/jwwtmr9jv/vs_image.png) double click item will give you option to change the list. But by default it is generally not required. Until it is changed. If you feel that you have messed everything. Just unistall vs and reinstall it. Every thing will be back to normal

Comment: @Angelica, maybe that would have solved the problem but i ended up doing a reinstall of VS, after which the problem disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Image of Visual Studio C++ Include Directories]

Double clicking item will give you option to change the list. But by default it is generally not required. Until it is changed. If you feel that you have messed everything. **Just uninstall visual studio and reinstall it.** Every thing will be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you've resolved it by now, but for others who experience this issue,
unless you directly deleted files from installed visual studio directory I wouldn't resort to an uninstall/reinstall solution, because then you don't know what went wrong and why.

When I ran into this issue. Two things I had to check and fix to resolve

1. XML file may have been directly edited, and butchered

   - Edit .vcxproj file, make sure that paths between **IncludePath**, and **LibraryPath** tags aren't separated by new lines (cr/lf)
2. Project properties may no longer be including default directories.

   - Right click project properties. Navigate to VC++ Directories, and select "inherit from parent or project defaults" for: Executable Directories, Reference Directories, Library WinRT Directories, Source Directories, Exclude Directories.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Visual Studio Project i downloaded from [github](https://github.com/powturbo/Turbo-Base64) .

Issue was the **Windows SDK Version** was set to a version i **hadn't installed**.
I solved it by changing the Configuration Properties -> General -> Windows SDK Version to **"< inherit from parent or project defaults >"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmph try unsistalling and reinstalling Visual Studio this thing happened to me 2 years ago on Vs 2017 because I opened a broken source andd it broke my visual studio :(

Comment: I would mark it as comments instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once. The reason was: in VC++ Directories > Include Directories option I had ";" at the end of the line. I edited that property and left a symbol there. It should end with "$(IncludePath)". After removing that character I managed to get it working.

Instead of reinstalling Visual Studio review your project settings.

Cleaning and rebuilding project may help, as well as closing and reloading project. You may also try removing binary build artifacts generated for your project, such as .lib and .obj